# MVC 4 - Force DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

Is it possible to force a DateTime object to use a different locale? I wish to populate a DateTime object with a UK DateTime but formatted as US.

I have tried the following:

```
DateTime ukDateTimeFormat = DateTime.Parse("10/26/2009 06:47", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"));
DateTime usDateTimeFormat = DateTime.Parse("26/10/2009 06:47", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-gb"));

string strDate = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string[] dateString = strDate.Split('/');
DateTime enterDate = DateTime.Parse(dateString[0] + "/" + dateString[1] + "/" + dateString[2], CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"));
```

Nothing works, I always end up with a UK formatted date.

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: `DateTime`s just store a time; they have no notion of format.

Comment: And it doesn't have _any_ culture.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you're confused between **representing** a date-time and **formatting** a date-time.

`DateTime` does not contain any format, it only represents the actual time. So the question about a US/UK format of a DateTime is meaningless.

If you want to display the time in a different format, that's not a `DateTime`, that's a `string`. You can use the various overloads of `DateTime.ToString(...)` in order to achieve different formatting as a string. There are some built-in formats, and you can specify a locale.

Comment: We are being requested by a third party to pass a DateTime object to a SOAP service and it must be formatted as a US DateTime, we cannot pass a string.

Comment: This requirement is meaningless. A DateTime can have a timezone, it can't have a format.

Comment: @iggyweb - within the call to a soap service (which will be passing XML), this will definitely be a string at some point...

Comment: Apologies, I meant Web Service not SOAP Service.

Answer (score 3):

The `DateTime` object does not have an internal string format as such - your date is stored as a date and formatted on output.  You can populate however you wish, however when outputting it, you'll need to specify your format, e.g.:

```
string formattedDate = ukDateFormat.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
```

Comment: Use an `IFormatProvider` as a second parameter because this _might_ generate different results because of `/` format specifier.

Answer (score 0):

To format your date for the locale, use this code:

```
string formattedDate = ukDateFormat.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-us"))
```